# Bug in multi-dimensional array program in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char

I've made a C program that involves multi-dimensional arrays (it prints a multi-dimensional array of characters) to review a little, but I came across a bug.

My expected output of the program is:

```
.
.
.
A
.
.
.
.
.
```

However the output I get is:

```
.
.
A     //Not meant to be 'A' but rather a '.'
A
.
.
.
.
.
```

**I am wondering how I get that extra 'A' in position [0][2], and how I can fix this problem.**

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void initArray(char shape[][2]);

main()
{
      char shape[2][2];
      int i, j;

      initArray(shape);
      shape[1][0] = 'A';
      printf("%c\n%c\n%c\n", shape[0][0], shape[0][1], shape[0][2]);  
      printf("%c\n%c\n%c\n", shape[1][0], shape[1][1], shape[1][2]);
      printf("%c\n%c\n%c\n", shape[2][0], shape[2][1], shape[2][2]);

      getchar();
}

void initArray(char shape[][2])
{
      int  i, j;

      for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
      {
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                  shape[i][j] = '.';                  
            }
      }
}
```

Thank you very much =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to loop till `< 2` as `shape` is declared as `shape[2][2]`

```
 for(i = 0; i < 2;i++)
   for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
```

This will iterate over the `shape` on row & columns `0-1` both inclusive

Comment: This makes the program print only 4 characters.  I've edited the program above, please check the edit

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner `i = 0; i < 3; i ++` will loop for `0,1,2`
accessing `shape[i][2]` or `shape[2][j]` is an undefined behavior when shape is just declared as `char shape[2][2];`
If you need total `9` elements just use `char shape[3][3];` and the current code will work fine

Comment: @POW so even in the edited program, the problem is that it should be declared as `char shape[3][3];` rather than `char shape[2][2];`?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way would be to avoid multi-dimensional arrays, and use plain arrays. Then instead of `char shape[2][2];` you would declare

```
 char shape[4];
```

and code `shape[2*i+j]` instead of `shape[i][j]`. (BTW the compiler transforms the later into the former).

Use a debugger (like `gdb`) to see if `i` and `j` have meaningful values. And add `assert(i>=0 && i<2)` at appropriate places.

Remember that an array declared `char arr[4];` (like my `shape` above) accepts only index from 0 to 3 (i.e. 4-1) i.e. use `arr[0]`, ... `arr[3]` or `arr[i]` with the integral `i` between 0 and 3. Accessing `arr[4]` (or `arr[17]` or `arr[i+1]` when `i` is 3) is an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (anything could happen per the C standard, including the collapse of the universe, which would be standard compliant). This particular error is quite common and called a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). It is used in malware.

Comment: upvote, because multidimension arrays have another problem. If you think of multidimensional arrays as single arrays you like sometimes to do something like `int array[5][5]; array[0][6] = x;`whats adressing a suitable adress, but is leading into undefined behavior

Comment: Thank you, but the idea of this review was to review multi-dimensional arrays in particular

Comment: I still believe you should not use them. In 30+ years of C programming, I almost never used them.