# Code won't run correctly

Tags: c

This code is meant to read the value from an image file into an array (I know the size is 16*8).

When I dynamically create the img array so I can have any size image it crashes when run, when I manually make it the correct size (`char img[16][8];`) it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fin;
    fin= fopen ("test.pgm","rb");
    if (fin == NULL)
    {
        printf ("ERROR");
        fclose(fin);
    }

    int i=0,j=0,u=16,v=8,d;
    char test[20];
    char k;
    char c[10];
    while((k=fgetc(fin))!='\n')
    {
        test[j]=k;  
        j=j+1;
    }

    char **img = (char**) calloc(u,sizeof(char*));
    for ( i = 0; i < u; i++ )
    {
        img[i] = (char*) calloc(v,sizeof(char));
    }

    fread(img,1,(u*v),fin);
    for (i=0; i<u; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<v; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",img[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fin);
}
```

Comment: How about telling us where the crash occurs...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18549885/841108

Comment: I use gcc to compile and when I enter the .exe to run a window pops up saying it has stopped working correctly

Comment: Right, do you know what line is causing the crash? Run it through a debugger

Comment: It is a  good question, doesn't down-vote.

Comment: @John This doesn't answer the question you posted, but should help you understand what the memory looks like. Apologies for the terrible C, I have written barely any in years: http://pastebin.com/Ur51wvq8.
Notice that when you do your second, pointer-based implementation that the _actual `char`s_ are allocated _after_ all of the `char *`s! (Whoops there's a small typo in the code. Line 24 should just be `&(img_1[i])` but it's... actually the exact same value).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, could you elaborate why this is a good question? I don't see a question at all.

Comment: Please put more effort in asking questions, here. Give it a title that summarizes your problem, explain what is going wrong ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dynamically allocating 16 separate 8 byte arrays, you will then need to compute 16 individual reads into each of those arrays. (I have removed the unnecessary, and potentially bug prone, casts to `calloc()`).

```
char **img = calloc(u,sizeof(char*));
for ( i = 0; i < u; i++ )
    {
    img[i] = calloc(v,sizeof(char));
    fread(img[i],1,v,fin);
    }

/*fread(img,1,(u*v),fin);*/
```

The single `fread()` call you had works for `char img[16][8]`, because in that case, `img` consists of contiguous memory sized at `16 * 8` bytes. But, that call will not work for the way you have created your dynamically allocated array, since `img` is now an array of pointers, and so the `fread()` call you have will overwrite those pointer values with data from the file.

If you want to do a single call to `fread()`, then you can change your dynamic allocation (and combine with VLA)

```
char (*img)[v];
img = malloc(u * sizeof(*img));
fread(img,1,(u*v),fin);
```

This declares `img` to be a pointer to an array `v` of `char` (`v` was initialized to 8). It then allocates `u` (ie, 16) many of  array `v` of `char` in a contiguous allocation for `img`. Now, `img` can be used for the single `fread()` call like you had for `char img[16][8]`, and also preserves the same "2D" addressing of `img` as well.

Comment: Jxh... Nice!....., you can also suggest him continue memory allocation.. I think possible?

Comment: thanks. Why don't you have to do this when you use char img[16][8];. Isn't it still the same format?

Comment: @John It's actually not the same memory structure at all... It's honestly a bit tricky, but try drawing out the 2D array on paper and then draw the calloc-based implementation on paper. It'll be very different. If you don't have a grasp of pointers then you might need to read up on them first.

Comment: @John: I've expanded my answer to explain why it is not the same. In essence, your dynamic allocation uses an array of pointers, and your `fread()` call is overwriting those pointer values you had stored the results of `malloc()` before.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I have added an alternative method to allocate dynamically and contiguously, that preserves the "2D" indexing.

Comment: @jxh Really a Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18691802/15168) by [jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315052/jxh) correctly diagnoses the trouble with the original code, which this answer does not (in part because of that).  It also demonstrates the power of variable length arrays, VLAs, which were added to C99.  It is really neat and should be accepted.

If you are stuck with C89 (perhaps because you work on Windows with MSVC), then you can still do the single read if you allocate the space contiguously.  However, if you're also going to use the double index notation, you still need the array of pointers, or you will need to use the notation `img[i*v+j]` (and a different type for `img`).  This code implements the extra array of pointers, and also includes a variety of other minor bug fixes to the original code (the most important being that it returns after failing to open the file, rather than reporting 'ERROR' and continuing as if nothing had gone wrong, including attempting to `fclose()` a null pointer, which is good for a crash).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *filename = "test.pgm";
    FILE *fin = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fin == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR opening file %s\n", filename);
        return(1);
    }

    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int u=16;
    int v=8;
    char test[20];
    int k;

    while ((k = fgetc(fin)) != '\n')
        test[j++] = k;
    test[j] = '\0';
    printf("test: %s\n", test);

    char **img = (char**) calloc(u,sizeof(char*));
    char *space = (char *)calloc(u*v, sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < u; i++)
        img[i] = &space[v*i];

    if (fread(img[0], 1, (u*v), fin) != (size_t)(u*v))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: short read\n");
        return(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < u; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < v; j++)
            printf("%3d ", img[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(fin);
    free(img[0]);
    free(img);
    return(0);
}
```

Note that the loop reading into `test` is not properly error checked; it could overflow, and it doesn't detect EOF, either.

Input data:

```
abcdefghij
aaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
ccccccc
ddddddd
eeeeeee
fffffff
ggggggg
hhhhhhh
iiiiiii
jjjjjjj
kkkkkkk
lllllll
mmmmmmm
nnnnnnn
ooooooo
ppppppp
```

Output data:

```
test: abcdefghij
 97  97  97  97  97  97  97  10 
 98  98  98  98  98  98  98  10 
 99  99  99  99  99  99  99  10 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100  10 
101 101 101 101 101 101 101  10 
102 102 102 102 102 102 102  10 
103 103 103 103 103 103 103  10 
104 104 104 104 104 104 104  10 
105 105 105 105 105 105 105  10 
106 106 106 106 106 106 106  10 
107 107 107 107 107 107 107  10 
108 108 108 108 108 108 108  10 
109 109 109 109 109 109 109  10 
110 110 110 110 110 110 110  10 
111 111 111 111 111 111 111  10 
112 112 112 112 112 112 112  10
```

Comment: I showed a way to do contiguous read and 2D addressing without an array of pointers.

Comment: Hmm... it shouldn't. It is using a pointer to a VLA, so it can index `img[i][j]` just fine.

Comment: No, I'm not saying the solution is invalid, just that you don't need the array of pointers. +1.

Comment: @jxh: I've updated my answer and deleted my comments.  I like your C99/VLA solution a lot; it hadn't occurred to me that was possible. I've recommended your solution as the 'modern' solution.  The only time my solution is preferable is if you're stuck with C89 — as a lot of developers on Windows are because they use MSVC.

Comment: Thanks! I agree that array of pointers are required if the number of columns is dynamic and you need the double index notation with a pre-C99 compiler.

Comment: @jxh: (_We're in agreement._) If the array size is fixed at compile time, then all the angst can be avoided, especially if, as is likely, all the data for an image is packaged into a single structure.  It only gets interesting if the array size is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You fread into your array of pointers but they point to various places in memory so that will not work.

In order for it to work set pointers to point to the same block but at different offsets

so instead of

```
char **img = calloc(u,sizeof(char*));
for ( i = 0; i < u; i++ )
{
    img[i] = calloc(v,sizeof(char));
}
```

do

```
char **img = calloc(u,sizeof(char*));
char *block = calloc(u*v,sizeof(char);
for ( i = 0; i < u; i++ )
{
    img[i] = block + v*i;
}
```

then

```
fread(block,1,(u*v),fin);
```